# Jquery clone with last input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to make a schedule payment module with **JS** my code works absolutely fine but I have a very small requirement but I am totally confused to accomplish this requirement. Actually I want to copy the values of last cloned input fields (both date and amount fields) but I want a date field to be increased by **one (1) month** of last selected value. I tried all the possible fields but no still no success.

**Here is my fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/9yvm5cj4/

**Here is my JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('<div/>', {
     'class': 'ScheduleextraPart',
     html: GetHtmls()
   }).appendTo('#Schedulecontainer');
   $('#ScheduleaddRow').click(function() {
     $('<div/>', {
       'class': 'ScheduleextraPart',
       html: GetHtmls()
     }).hide().appendTo('#Schedulecontainer').slideDown('fast');
   });
 })

 function GetHtmls() {
   var lens = $('.ScheduleextraPart').length;
   var $htmls = $('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').clone();
   $htmls.find('[name=txtSchedule]')[0].name = "txtSchedule" + lens;
   $htmls.find('[name=txtScheduleAmountPay]')[0].name = "txtScheduleAmountPay" + lens;
   return $htmls.html();
 }
```

Comment: If you're just adding 1 to your month, then you could write something fairly easily (just remember upping the year too after 12).  But take a look into moment.js.  They handle this sort of thing

Comment: i tried all the possible way i knew but failed everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of had to redo a lot of your code to really understand what was happening.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yvm5cj4/31/) for a working verison.

When the page loads, I grab a version of the form template and clone it, then I remove it (easier for validation and whatnot), then append it.  Simple enough.

```
var formItem;
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Clone and remove your div instead of hiding it
    formItem = $('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').clone();
    $('.ScheduleextraPartTemplate').remove();
    formItem.addClass('clone clone-1');
    $('#Schedulecontainer').append(formItem);
});
```

The tricky part comes with the onclick event.  When the user clicks, I clone the last form group, change the class so it's iterative, then retrieve the date in the input.  After I retrieve the date, I run a new function that adds +1 to the month (and checks if it's over 12, add +1 to the year).

```
$(document).on('click', '#ScheduleaddRow', function() {
    var cloneForm = $('.clone').last().clone();
    var cloneNum = $('.clone').length;
    cloneForm.removeClass('clone-'+cloneNum).addClass('clone-' + (cloneNum+1));
    var date = cloneForm.find('[name="txtSchedule"]').val();
    cloneForm.find('[name="txtSchedule"]').val(addOneMonth(date));
    cloneForm.find('[name="txtSchedule"]')[0].name = "txtSchedule" + (cloneNum+1);
    cloneForm.find('[name="txtScheduleAmountPay"]')[0].name = "txtScheduleAmountPay" + (cloneNum+1);
    $('#Schedulecontainer').append(cloneForm);
});

function addOneMonth(date) {
    var year = parseInt(date.split("-")[0]);
    var month = parseInt(date.split("-")[1]) + 1;
    var day = parseInt(date.split("-")[2]);
    if(month > 12) {
        month = month - 12;
        year++
    }
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}
```

Comment: Looks great but there is problem when adding new clone it must add an increment in field name from zero to the number isn't possible?

Comment: This is possible, I just overlooked that detail. When I get back to the computer I will fix that.

Comment: Ok sure I'll be waiting for your reply @ntgCleaner

Comment: @Rtra, Sorry - my wife and I are in the hospital now having our second baby!  I had some down time and fixed that.  I added two lines to the code above.  All of these are at a base of 1, instead of zero.  If that's a problem just subtract 1 from the original cloneNum

Comment: Oh thats great to hear. no problem take your time. well the codes works but its only adding 1 new clone